# Operators precedence in Drools rule

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, mvel

Hi I want to know how the following rule gets interpreted in Drools

```
rule "test"
when
    condiction A
    or
    condiction B
    condiction C
then something
end
```

Is it

1. (A or B) and C
2. A or (B and C)
3. becomes two rules: a). A and C  b). B and C
4. becomes two rules: a). A b). B and C

Thank you

Comment: After trying it out, you still can't eliminate any of the four possibilities? That is very odd. What problems have you had while trying it out?

Comment: Not that I am having any troubles, I just want to confirm with someone. My testing showed it is case 3. But none here agreed with me, so I am still confused. Try to give me and the rest some useful input Marko.

Comment: You mean the condition is `(A and C) or (B and C)`? In other words, `(A or B) and C`? Yes, that's what I'd say, too. The least precedence is given to the evaluation of separate `when` clauses. It is not at all the same as imagining an `and` between them. Yes, I'd say the docs are misleading there and I'm even starting to remember I wondered the same when I did my Drools project (it's been a while now).

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence in Drools (largely) follows Java operator precedence. ***Ands*** (&) are evaluated before ***ors*** (|), which are evaluated before ***logical ands*** (&&), which are evaluated before ***logical ors*** (||).

```
Operator precedence ---->

&    |    &&    ||
```

Note that Drools *does* support explicit operand grouping with parentheses, so when in doubt use them. As is, in your example the evaluation order corresponds to #2:

A or (B and C)

This ordering is then compiled into two rules, based off the groupings:

```
A
B and C
```

Either of these rules may then be activated, depending on your model.

All this is explained in the ***highly*** recommended [Drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e5351).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have read the document. According to 4.8.3.6.2., 'or' is actually rewritten into more sub-rules, so I think for my example, it is case 3.

Comment: You two sub rules are 1) A 2) B and C, which directly derive from the operator grouping (A or (B and C)). Which sub rules fire after the grouping is done is then based on your model.

Comment: Thanks again. What I have tested is to have C modifying some stuff and when A fired, it picked that up (it wouldn't be if it is just A), so I tend to think it becomes (A and C) or (B and C)